# Java paint Component loop

Tags: java, for-loop, paintcomponent

I  need to make a loop with `paintComponent`

Like this

```
 public class Screen extends JComponent
 {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.fillOval(Main.x, Main.y, 20, 20);

    }
    {
    for(int c = 0; c<10; c++)
    {

        paintComponent(g);
    }

  }
```

The methods are in a class that extends `JComponent`.

In the for loop java gives me an error

`g` cannot be resolved to a variable

Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post the complete code snippet, for example `for` loop by itself doesn't mean anything, surrounding code where in `for` loop is present will give us more clear picture

Comment: I posted, it's a really small class

Comment: It's just paintComponent method and the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is not enclosed within block or method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.fillOval(Main.x, Main.y, 20, 20);

    }// method closed here itself

    //{
    //for(int c = 0; c<10; c++)
    //{
        //paintComponent(g);//here `g` is not declared
    //}
```

Comment: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call `paintComponent(Graphics g)` that is why we have repaint() method and you should know that Graphics is an abstract class you cannot create
instance of it.
another thing i am assuming that you trying to make an animated ball to be able to do that you should read about swing timer first. i am learning java too, so just keep trying.